# PHP/MVC : in this case, how to use DTO?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, dto

I'm new to OOP and MVC with PHP, and I'm currently learning by making my own custom framework from scratch, for testing purposes. I have set up my controllers, models and views and everything works fine.

My app has the following architecture :

[image: Screen from IDE that show app directory]

It’s a small blog that follows the rules of the MVC pattern. To summarize, it works like this :

- The called Controller will fetch the data using the right models
- Models return objects of the class `\Classes\{MyObject}`
- Controller call the right template to render the view, and passes it the data and objects to display

### The problem

In some views, I need to display related data. For example, in the article view, I need to display the author's first name. In the database, an article contains only the author’s ID, not his first name : this is the same thing in my class `\Classes\Article`.

### What I've tried

To display the author’s first name in my view, I've updated the model `Find` method to use a LEFT JOIN in the SQL query. Then, I've updated my `\Classes\Article` class to have a `user_firstname` property :

```
class Article
{
    private $pk_id;
    private $title;
    private $excerpt;
    private $content;
    private $created_at;
    private $fk_user_id;
    private $updated_at;
    private $user_firstname; // <-- I've added this property to retrieve author's firstname

// (...)
}
```

What I did works well, but my teacher tells me it’s not the right way to do it because the author’s firstname is not part of the definition of an article.

In this case, my teacher tells me to use a DTO (Data Transfert Object) between `Article` and `User` classes.

### Questions

- What is the right way to set up a DTO in this case?
- Do I need to create a new ArticleUserDTO class in a new namespace ?
- How to use it ?

I think I understood the problem : the `Article` class should only contain what defines an article. But I can’t understand the logic of setting up a DTO. I’ve done some research on it, I understand the usefulness of the DTO but I can’t set up into my app.

Comment: DTO is plain object with rules which described https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html . You create object with data what you want and MAP/fill/set data to your DTO object from Entity. Check internet there are plenty tutorials for that.

Comment: To create this object, I will need a class : for example ```\Classes\Post```, which will collect the data between an article and its author. 
After that, I just have to transfer this DTO object to my view, instead of transferring the original ```\Classes\Article``` object to it. 
Is this the right thing to do ? 
Does it follow the good practices of MVC ?

Comment: in your controller you get data from Article and create new Post and map/set the values into Post and controller return the Post object. You are right

Comment: It's much clearer to me now ! I'm going to try this. Thank you !

Comment: You have _models_ and _classes_, what is the distinction between these?

Comment: @ChrisHaas **Models** are used to interact with the database (find, insert, update or delete an item). The model methods usually return a `\Class` object, or use a `\Class` object as parameter.
**Classes** are the real representations of items. An item has a title, a content, a creation datetime, etc.

Comment: In 20+ years I’ve never actively used MVC, just happened to use something that is similar, so I’m honestly not that familiar with it beyond just theory. No judgement in any way, and honestly lots of ignorance on my part probably, too. But, MVC is called MVC, and not MVC + classes. If you are that loosely coupled, however, I’d think you’d really have MVC + DTO, which is totally fine, too. Or maybe I’m just hung up on “classes”, since everything in this MVC paradigm is really a class, and they should be called “entities” or similar.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I'm OOP/MVC learner, so I am not an expert, but your comment is interesting ! As a beginner, I want to make clean code and follow good practices as possible. I have chosen `Classes` namespace without asking myself before, maybe `entities` is a better choice and follows MVC standards ?

Answer (score 2):

Setting up a DTO in my app was easy ! As mentioned by @daremachine, the diagram below helped me to understand what a DTO is for.

[image: DTO scheme from MartinFowler.com]
*Diagram source : [martinfowler.com](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)*

We can see DTOs as an object assembler, in which we place all the elements we need on the view side.

For example, in the post view of an article, I needed to display other items, such as the author and posted comments. So I have created a Post class that groups all these items.

### Setting up a DTO

In my `\Classes\` namespace, I've created a new `Post` class. First, we define the properties we will need. Then we add the getters and setters for each of them. Finally, we set up the constructor, which will call each of the classes we need in the view.

```
namespace Classes;

use DateTime;

class Post
{
    private int $pk_id;
    private string $title;
    private string $excerpt;
    private string $content;
    private DateTime $created_at;
    private DateTime $updated_at;
    private int $author_id;
    private string $author_firstname;
    private array $comments;

    public function __construct(Article $article, User $author, array $comments)
    {
        $this->setPkId($article->getId());
        $this->setTitle($article->getTitle());
        $this->setExcerpt($article->getExcerpt());
        $this->setContent($article->getContent());
        $this->setCreatedAt($article->getCreatedAt());
        $this->setUpdatedAt($article->getUpdatedAt());
        $this->setAuthorId($article->getAuthorId());
        $this->setAuthorFirstname($author->getFirstname());
        $this->setComments($comments);
    }

    /**
     * @param int $pk_id
     */
    public function setPkId(int $pk_id): void
    {
        $this->pk_id = $pk_id;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getPkId(): int
    {
        return $this->pk_id;
    }

    // (etc)
}
```

We now need to update the `ArticleController`, which should no longer pass the `Article`, `Comment` and `User` objects, but only the new `Post` object.

```
namespace Controllers;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
  // (...)

     /**
     * Get an article and display it
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function show(): void
    {
        // (...)

        // Find Article :
        $article = $this->articleModel->find($article_id);

        if (!$article) {
            Http::error404();
        }

        // Find Comments :
        $commentaires = $this->commentModel->findAllByArticle($article_id);

        // Find User (author)
        $user = $this->userModel->find($article->getAuthorId());

        // Data Transfert Object instance :
        $post = new Post($article, $user, $commentaires);

        $pageTitle = $post->getTitle();
        // Pass DTO to view :
        Renderer::render('articles/show', compact('pageTitle', 'post'));
    }
}
```

We just need to update our view to use the new Post object and it's done ! Thanks to @daremachine for his help :)